# Does boost have smart pointers for a vector of arrays?

Tags: c++, memory-management, boost

This is to hold a data like

```
double **a;
a = new (double*)[100];
for (int i=0; i<100; ++i) {
   a[i] = new double[99];
}
```

The ptr_vector can include a vector of pointers. But it does not seem supporting customized deleter to free an array.

One solution is that I can create a new class that manages 99 doubles, and use ptr_vector to hold 100 of the classes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best approach is to use the **Standard Library**. [`std::vector`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector)  saves you from having to worry about memory management and having to set the vector's size.

```
std::vector<std::vector<double>> a;
```

You can also use [`std::unique_ptr`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr), but it is more bothersome to allocate dynamic memory. However, since it is a std::unique_ptr is a **smart pointer** when the object destructs/runs out of scope, memory is automatically deallocated.

```
std::unique_ptr<std::unique_ptr<double>[]> a(new std::unique_ptr<double>[100]);
  for (i=0; i <100; i++)
      a[i] = std::unique_ptr<int[]>(new int[99]);
```

The above works, but it defeats the intent of `std::unique_ptr` which is to save you from using pointers and automatically allocating and deallocating memory.